# Battery management system for my battery packs

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, mosfet, adc, gate-driving

I'm working on battery management system for my battery cells.
the topology is based on inductor energy transfert from the higher charged cell to the lower one in order to balance and equalize the charge between the cells.
two main blocks are necessary in my circuit are first the monitor of voltage and driving mosfets.
i tried first to work with the BQ76PL536 from Texas Instruments but the problem is that his CBn output to drive the mosfet are Digital Output while i want to provide a PWM signal at 100Khz frequency so i dropped the solution and i'm trying to make my own discrete solution.

Gate driving is not a problem but i have some problems with voltage measurement to the microcontroller.
my cells voltage range are from 0V to 1.6V max.
i'm thinking on using voltage comparator for each cell and the output go to the microcontroller.

the other problem is that i'm going to measure this voltage while i'm charging the battery with 17A current.

[image: cell balancing with IC from texas that can monitor cell voltage]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Asking for opinions is off topic here. Please define a non open-ended question, start all your sentences with capital letter as well as capitalizing "I".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a differential amplifier to monitor each battery cell. You need to use ADCs (4 channels) from the uC to measure the battery cell voltages. You can then balance the cells by turning on the PWM signals in according the cell voltages. You may test your battery cell balancing implementation and algorithm by using a [battery simulator](http://www.accelinstruments.com/Applications/TS200/Battery-Simulator-AppNote.html) for each cell. You can use the battery simulator to vary each cell to test your balancing circuit.